# Check weekend and month conditions in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have written a stored procedure. I want to put a validation where FromDate and ToDate belongs to the same month or not. Bellow is what I have gotten so far.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SavingsAccountsAllDetail
(@FDate DATE=NULL,
@TDate DATE=NULL)

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @FromDate DATE
    DECLARE @ToDate DATE

    SET @FromDate = isnull(@FDate)
    SET @ToDate = isnull(@TDate)

    IF month(@FromDate) != month(dateadd(day,-1,@FromDate))
    BEGIN
    PRINT 'Not belongs to current month'
    END
```

I want to know if my approach is okay and how to add ToDate validation.

I also want to check if FromDate/ToDate is a weekend or not. If it is a weekend then PRINT 'Is a weekend'. If not proceed with the rest of the procedure. I would very much appreciate the support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may also want to check year as well. But for what you have asked. this is the way.

```
 IF month(@FromDate) !=  month(@ToDate)
 BEGIN
        RETURN; --Not same month
 END
```

weekend check

```
IF datepart(dw,@FromDate) IN (1,7) OR datepart(dw,@ToDate) IN (1,7)
BEGIN
      RETURN; --Weekend
END
```

Comment: Sorry current month I meant was if From/To Dates belongs to the same month or not, not actual month.

Comment: Yuh I saw , thanks so much for the support but how to update stored procedure to check both validations and if conditions are not met only proceed with the rest?

Comment: @DeEDEe : Just say `RETURN` inside both if blocks

Comment: Don't use a return statement inside procedure. For procedure return statement is used for returning the procedure status. Rather just `select`

Comment: How about like this? IF month(@FromDate) != month(@ToDate)
 BEGIN
 PRINT 'Not belongs to same month'
 RETURN
 IF datepart(dw,@FromDate) IN (1,7) OR datepart(dw,@ToDate) IN (1,7)
 BEGIN
 PRINT 'Belongs to weekend'
 END

Comment: @DeEDEe : you can obviously do that.